# Solving an equation matrix with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, matrix

Imagine I want to solve the following matrix system of equations
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\dot{x}_{11} & \dot{x}_{12} & \dot{x}_{13}\\
\dot{x}_{21} & \dot{x}_{22} & \dot{x}_{23}\\
\dot{x}_{31} & \dot{x}_{32} & \dot{x}_{33}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}x_{11} & a_{12}x_{12} & a_{13}x_{13}\\
a_{21}x_{21} & a_{22}x_{22} & a_{23}x_{23}\\
a_{31}x_{31} & a_{32}x_{32} & a_{33}x_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $x_{ij}\equiv x_{ij}(t)$ and $\{a_{ij}\}$ are some real coefficients. When $\{a_{ij}\}=1$, we can solve this with `NDSolveValue` as follows

```
ini = RandomReal[1, {3, 3}];
sol = NDSolveValue[{
   x'[t] == x[t],
   x[0] == ini
   }, x, {t, 0, 1}]
```

for some random initial conditions `ini` (also a matrix). Now, how can I include custom coefficients? Specifically, what if the coefficient matrix is such that the diagonal is zero and all the other entries are 1? That is,

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\dot{x}_{11} & \dot{x}_{12} & \dot{x}_{13}\\
\dot{x}_{21} & \dot{x}_{22} & \dot{x}_{23}\\
\dot{x}_{31} & \dot{x}_{32} & \dot{x}_{33}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & x_{12} & x_{13}\\
x_{21} & 0 & x_{23}\\
x_{31} & x_{32} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I tried setting

```
coeff = ConstantArray[1, {3, 3}] - IdentityMatrix[3]
```

followed simply by

```
ini = RandomReal[1, {3, 3}];
sol = NDSolveValue[{
   x'[t] == coeff * x[t],
   x[0] == ini
   }, x, {t, 0, 1}]
```

However this doesn't seem to work and I get the error message

[image]

which seems to be related with how `NDSolveValue` is interpreting `coeff`

[image]

I've noticed that, although `x[t]` within the `NDSolve` environment can be tretaed as a list or a list of lists, it fails its interpretation in some cases. Any ideas?

Comment: why not work with the vector `{x11, x12, x13, x21, x22, x23, x31, x32, x33}` instead? Then you can use a matrix-vector dot product on the rhs. If you really need to use a matrix formulation, you can define a function `foo[x_List] := coeff x` and use that on the rhs.

Comment: I really need to use the matrix formulation. How exactly would I do that with the `foo` function?

Comment: use `x'[t] == foo[x[t]]`

Comment: That's great. Any idea why this works in this case? What is `x[t]` for `NDSolve`? Is it really a list? I often get confused by this.

Comment: Evaluate `x'[t] == coeff x[t]`. Since `x[t]` is not a matrix yet, it is treated as a scalar and x[t] is threaded into the matrix. Using `foo` prevents this early multiplication.

Comment: I see. I noticed it treats it as a scalar, however, with `Dot` or `.` I saw no problem. I've been using it for the case of column systems (the usual one, like you suggested, not matrices). For example, I define a matrix `A` as the adjacency matrix of a certain graph on which I have my system and simply do `A.x[t]`. This is still correct, right?

Comment: @samwolfe yes that's right. You can try it yourself. Compare `{{a,b},{c,d}}.x[t]` with `{{a,b}, {c, d}}*x[t]`.

Comment: Interestingly enough, `Transpose` is also ok (if I want something like $\dot{x}_{ij}=x_{ji}$).

Comment: It is because all of these functions expect their arguments to be `List`s. So if you give `foo` or `Dot` or `Transpose` the argument `x[t]`, it won't evaluate and everything will work like you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue is premature evaluation of the product between `coeff` and `x[t]`. Before `NDSolve` evaluates `x[t]` with the initial condition, it performs

```
coeff*x[t] = {{0,x[t],x[t]}, {x[t],0,x[t]},{x[t],x[t],0}}
```

Then when it substitutes in the initial condition, each of those `x[t]`s becomes a matrix and you end up with a mess. The idea is to stop the scalar * matrix product happening until `x[t]` is evaluated to be a matrix. This can be accomplished by using any function which expects a `List` as an argument and remains unevaluated if the argument is not a list. @CarolWoll suggests in the comments using `foo[x_List]:=coeff*x`. We can see that

```
mat={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
coeff*x[t] = {{0,x[t],x[t]},{x[t],0,x[t]},{x[t],x[t],0}}
coeff*x[t] = {{0,x[t],x[t]},{x[t],0,x[t]},{x[t],x[t],0}}/.x[t]->mat =
    {{0,{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}},{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}},{{{1,2,3},
{4,5,6},{7,8,9}},0,{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}},{{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}},
{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}},0}} (* huge mess *)
foo[x[t]]=foo[x[t]]
foo[mat]={{0,2,3},{4,0,6},{7,8,0}} (* as desired *)
```