# Parts of a Piecewise Matrix Function in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, evaluation, piecewise, list-manipulation, discontinuity

First time posting.

**Reproducing the Problem**

I'm relatively new to Mathematica (using v.12.3), and working on a project. My problem can be reproduced with this.

```
m[x_] := {{x, 0}, {0, x}}

f[x_] := Piecewise[{{m[x], x <= 5}}, m[1]]

test = NDSolve[{y'[t] == f[t][[1, 1]], y[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Outside of NDSolve, `f[t][[1,1]]` evaluates as expected using the Piecewise function (i.e., `f[3][[1,1]] = m[3][[1,1]]` but `f[10][[1,1]] = m[1][[1,1]]`).

However, NDSolve does not seem to evaluate the Piecewise function before attempting to use it, as the stack trace gives:

```
NDSolve[{Derivative[1][y][t] == {{{t, 0}, {0, t}}, t <= 5}, y[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 10}]
```

**Attempted Solutions & Workarounds**

Moving the Piecewise statement within NDSolve seems to produce the expected result.

```
m[x_] := {{x, 0}, {0, x}}

f[x_] := m[x]

test = NDSolve[{
  y'[t] == Piecewise[{{f[t][[1, 1]], t <= 5}}, m[1][[1, 1]]], 
  y[0] == 0}, 
  y, {t, 0, 10}]
```

I also tried `If` statements:

```
m[x_] := {{x, 0}, {0, x}}

f[x_] := If[x >= 10, m[x], m[1]]

test = NDSolve[{y'[t] == f[t][[1, 1]], y[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 10}]
```

However, this appears to ignore the `If` statement entirely when comparing the outputs using `Plot[y[t] /. test, {t, 0, 10}]`.

I have looked around extensively on StackExchange and the documentation for solutions, but haven't come up with much besides a suspicion that it's

- something to do with a Hold or Delay property that I don't know about, and/or
- something to do with syntax I don't know about, and/or
- [something to do with how NDSolve works?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250329/solving-an-equation-matrix-with-ndsolve)

I would appreciate an explanation for why this behavior occurs (or something I can look up to find that information myself; maybe I don't know what to look for), as I've been struggling for some 8+ hours on this. Thank you!

**Edit:** All excellent responses; thank you so much!

Comment: Somewhat related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97006/1871

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to use [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed) instead of [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part):

```
test = NDSolveValue[{y'[t] == Indexed[f[t], {1,1}], y[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 10}];
ListPlot[test]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Define functions for numerical input and create a second function `g[t_?NumericQ]` , that takes the desired part of f.

```
m[x_] = {{x, 0}, {0, x}};

f[x_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[{{m[x], x <= 5}}, m[1]]

g[t_?NumericQ] := f[t][[1, 1]]

ysol = y /. Flatten@NDSolve[{y'[t] == g[t], y[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 10}]

Plot[ysol[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of evaluation order. Since `NDSolve` doesn't own attribute like `HoldAll`, `HoldFirst`, etc., the equation will automatically evaluate before fed into `NDSolve` i.e. what happens here is amount to

```
sys = {y'[t] == f[t][[1, 1]], y[0] == 0}
(* {y'[t] == {{{t, 0}, {0, t}}, t <= 5}, y[0] == 0} *)
test = NDSolve[sys, y, {t, 0, 10}]
(* NDSolve::ndnum *)
```

You can verify this with `Trace`:

```
NDSolve[{y'[t] == f[t][[1, 1]], y[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 10}] // Trace
```

[image]

So how to circumvent? Generally somewhat advanced techniques for evaluation order adjustion may be needed, but the matrix inside your `Piecewise` is just an explicit matrix formed by 4 arithmetic expressions, so we can simply use `` Simplify`PWToUnitStep ``:

```
Clear[x];
m[x_] = {{x, 0}, {0, x}};
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{m[x], x <= 5}}, m[1]] // Simplify`PWToUnitStep
(*
{{1 - UnitStep[5 - x] + x UnitStep[5 - x], 0}, 
 {0, 1 - UnitStep[5 - x] + x UnitStep[5 - x]}}
 *)

NDSolveValue[{y'[t] == f[t][[1, 1]], y[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 10}]
% // ListPlot
```

[image]

Here I've made use of an undocumented syntax of `ListPlot`. See [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134223/1871) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your function `F[x_] := If [x >= 10, f[t][[1,1]], m[1][[1,1]] ]` remains unevaluated when condition `x >= 10` evaluates to neither True or False.
So,

```
In[1]:= f[t] (*evaluating at x = t, for t a symbol*)

Out[1]= If[t >= 10, m[t], m[1]]
```

Then the expression

```
In[2]:= f[t][[1]]

Out[2]= t >= 10
```

and finally you have

```
In[3]:= f[t][[1, 1]] (* equivalently f[t][[1]][[1]]*)

Out[3]= t
```

The expression in `Out[3]` remains unchanged when you used in

```
test = NDSolve[{y'[t] == f[t][[1, 1]], y[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 10}]
(*equivalently*)
test = NDSolve[{y'[t] == t, y[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Something different occurs when you use Piecewise. This Piecewise command is
developed to be evaluated in expressions such as as Integrate, Minimize, Reduce, DSolve, and Simplify, as well as their numeric analogs. So, when you used inside
this last set of functions what occurs is something like this

```
Piecewise[{conditions in terms of t}] /. (t->(*evaluating at*) tt )
```

Comment: "Something different occurs when you use Piecewise. … So, when you used inside this last function what occurred is something like this `Piecewise[{conditions in terms of t}] /. (t->(*evaluating at*) tt )`" Not quite correct. What happens here is essentially the same as that happens on `If[…]`: `f[x][[1, 1]]` has evaulated to `{{{x, 0}, {0, x}}, x <= 5}`.